# Computing least square estimator with known derived data

Tags: regression, estimation, least-squares

I'm not an expert on this methods, and maybe my approach have some error. But I wanted to know how to compute a Least Square estimators given samples with different dimensions.

For example you have a sample $B:\{b_1\dots b_N\}$, and also a sample $C=\{c_1\dots c_M\}$ where $N\neq M$, and you also know the relation between them, that can be,  $$A=C+B$$

**How is possible to compute the LS estimator of $A$**. Least square function to minimize is,

$$\chi^2(\theta_A)= \sum \frac{(a_i-\lambda (x_i;\theta_A))^2}{\sigma^i}$$

Where $a_i$ is the data that will be measured. If we don't know the function $\lambda$ that describes $A$, what value should be $\lambda$?

The intuitive solution that comes to my mind is using the data we have form $B$ or $C$, compute $\lambda$ taking mean values of $B$ and $C$,
$$\lambda = \bar{B}+\bar{C}$$

But I don't know how to justify this propertly.

Comment: I don't think I understand you question or problem setup. what data are you trying to estimate and what data do you want to use to make the estimation? maybe it would be easier if you outline the exact (physical/commercial/etc) problem you have in mind

Comment: Hi, today I been rethinking about this problem and I edited the question and now is more clear. I rephrased the question to be more undertandable. I want to compute a estimator using LS where I can not use a function, only some measurements of related magnitudes (B,C)

Comment: If you don’t have $A$, I don’t see how you can do supervised learning of any kind.

Comment: But I have some measurements already done for $B$ and $C$, where $A=B+C$. I want to compute the estimator for the measures of $A$ that will be taken **in the future**

Comment: what do you mean by A=B+C. you can only add vectors of same dimension. do you mean that they are concatenated?  As suggested before please just give the concrete  problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: “Least squares” means the estimator that gives the lowest sum of squared differences between predictions and observations. If you lack the observations, I cannot see a way to do it.

Comment: For example with A,B and C being ,masses that $m_A=m_B+m_C$. I want to compute an estimator of the mass of $A$, that I can not measure at this moment. But I can measure the mass of B and C, **that is not the mass of A strictly** in statistic terms. And I want with data of $B$ and $C$ to create an estimator for the mass of $A$.

Comment: Is not getting a value given a dataset ${a_1,...a_N}$, I want to compute an expression that you can use in the future **with any dataset of $A$ given**

Comment: If your equation is $m_A=m_B+m_C$, there is no regression to estimate. You know that, once you get $m_B$ and $m_C$, you just add them. // Please add the pertinent details that describe what you aim to do. It is hard to answer a question when we have to guess what the question is.  // If the question truly is that you want a least squares estimator of $A$ but have no observations of $A$, the answer is that you can’t do it, and no one is entitled to a solution just because they want one or their boss wants one.